# How do I push an object in to an array that is contained within a deeply embedded document?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to push a new object to an array contained within an embedded document. Somehow I don't have the code quite right. Here is what I have tried:

Model:

```
var subCommentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    user : String,
    title : String,
    sub_comment : String,
    created : {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

var commentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    user : String,
    title : String,
    comment : String,
    created : {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    sub_comments : [subCommentSchema]
});

var postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    user : String,
    title : String,
    post : String,
    created : {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    comments : [commentSchema]
});
```

API Call:

```
app.post('/comment/:comment_id/sub-comment', function(req, res) {
    var updateData = {
        sub_comments: {
            title: req.body.title,
            sub_comment: req.body.sub_comment,
            user: req.user._id 
        }
    };
    Post.update(
        { "comments._id" : req.params.comment_id }, 
        { $push : updateData }, 
        function(err,data) {
            return res.json(data);
        }
    );
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the match on the [positional `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator in the update section. You will also want a "dot notation" form of this for the key to identify the "comments" field you are pushing into at the top level:

```
app.post('/comment/:comment_id/sub-comment', function(req, res) {
    var updateData = {
        "comments.$.sub_comments": {
            title: req.body.title,
            sub_comment: req.body.sub_comment,
            user: req.user._id 
        }
    };
    Post.update(
        { "comments._id" : req.params.comment_id }, 
        { $push : updateData }, 
        function(err,data) {
            return res.json(data);
        }
    );
});
```

That matches the index of the "comments" array by your supplied `_id` in the query and "pushes" your document into the "sub_comments" array at that position.